# Forum - Threaded Messaging on Mobile

Tags: mobile, mobile-web, mobile-application, forum

I need to display a threaded forum on Mobile. It's a fully fledged threaded forum where users can reply on any "reply".

Currently I am displaying the forum in threaded order, but as it is a small display size I can not show the depth of the reply after 3/4 reply chains. This makes it dfficult to understand and to relate to the replies.

I am considering following options

1. Show all threads in Time Sorted manner irrespective of thread (newest the first). This might also confuse the reader, about the parent for last reply.
2. Typical Navigation flow of mobile where I show only one parent and first childs of the parent, to view grand-childs I select on of the child. But this will have too many navigational back and forth for single forum
3. Display only Nodes of thread for last reply. i.e Showing only main Thread, Last reply and all nodes which binds them together.
   This will also include an option where user can view Entire Threaded Message

I want to know what is the best way I can display it mobile.

EDIT:

Actual Forum POST

[image]

Outline Mock

[image]

Comment: Please add a mockup/screenshot for either option, this will make it a *whole lot* easier to help you.

Comment: Ever seen [Threadvis](http://threadvis.github.io/documentation/)?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Reddit's mobile beta website.](https://m.reddit.com) They do waste quite a bit of space on the left site that could otherwise be used to fill content. But the hierarchy can be seen from a mile away.

The **lines that connect** each reply to its parent is a great idea as scrolling deep lets you track where and what you're reading. Having the **ability to fold a reply** is also a great idea.

> Show all threads in Time Sorted manner irrespective of thread (newest
>   the first). This might also confuse the reader, about the parent for
>   last reply.

You should consider sorting each levels by its recent post. This would not confuse the user.

> Typical Navigation flow of mobile where I show only one parent and
>   first childs of the parent, to view grand-childs I select on of the
>   child. But this will have too many navigational back and forth for
>   single forum

Sounds reasonable as mobile real estate is limited

> Display only Nodes of thread for last reply. i.e Showing only main
>   Thread, Last reply and all nodes which binds them together. This will
>   also include an option where user can view Entire Threaded Message

If you play around with the settings on Reddit, you'll see that they've implemented a similar system.

Obligatory screenshots (if you can't access the beta site)

**Reply buttons:**

[image: Reddit's new thread showing "reply" buttons on each reply]

**Nice hierarchy view:**

[image: Long Sample of the actual post]

**Awesome folding option:**

[image]

Comment: Well, this seems to be best solution till now, though there is waste of space for aligning the threads. But that's trade-off.

Comment: @VishalKardode here's an interesting read http://alistapart.com/article/whitespace

Answer (score 0):

On mobile you'll probably have to resort to a colour scheme that links each reply to its parent as well as the Original Post. Take a look at this simple threading done in a Hacker News client for iOS:

[image]

Comment: Our current Approach is simillar, except the color folds. We have used simple left-padding for depth selection.still after depth level 4/5 you loss almost 25% of the screen in padding.<br>Here you have shown screenshot of iPad which has more screen area than a mid range smartphone.I have to consider main smartphone users apart from Phablet / Tablet Users.

Answer (score 0):

How about using borders. Reply 1 border line will enclose reply 1-1, 1-2 and 1-1 encloses 1-1-1, 1-1-2 and so on.

Comment: It's hard for e to understand, can you please elaborate what you mean.

Comment: More like a box within another box. Although there will be some padding, it will be far lesser than using significant indenting. Ex: http://slashdot.org/ (If the boxes are colored and borderless, the padding can be decreased further)